# Equality of two symmetric maps

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-functions

Let $V$ and $W$ be two real vector spaces. I would like to show that two symmetric and multi-linear functions
$$\alpha_1,\alpha_2:V^n\to W$$
are equal if and only if
$$\forall v\in V:\alpha_1(v)=\alpha_2(v),$$
where $\alpha(v):=\alpha(v,\ldots,v)$.

The case $n=2$ is easy as $\alpha_1(v,w)=\alpha_2(v,w)$ follows from $\alpha_1(v+w,v+w)=\alpha_2(v+w,v+w)$ (note that scalar multiplication comes into play here).
I am not sure how to go to higher dimensions though (induction?). Note that we can not use the polarization formula
$$\alpha(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial t_1\cdots\partial t_n}\alpha(t_1v_1+\ldots+t_nv_n)$$
in [Nicolaescus's notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Lectures.pdf) as $W$ shall not be finite-dimensional. Is there perhaps a similar formula without derivatives?

**Motivation**:

I would like to show that the requirement
$$\forall(f_0,\ldots,f_n)\in C^\infty(M)^{n+1}:\left\{\prod_{i=0}^n\mathrm{ad}(f_i)\right\}T=0$$
for differential operators of order $n$ is equivalent to
$$\forall f\in C^\infty(M):\mathrm{ad}(f)^{n+1}T=0.$$

Comment: For $n=3$ start from $\alpha(u+v+w)$ and see how much of $\alpha(u+v)+\alpha(v+w)+\alpha(w+u)$ you need to subtract and so on until you have the pattern. You will find it explicitly in the references of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98714/generalization-of-the-polarisation-formula-for-symmetric-bilinear-forms-to-symme  , esp in the reference https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1275